# Laravel generated Insert query is not having values for column

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a MyModel::create($input) wihich generates following insert statement

```
insert into mytable (error, result, url, pareq, id, trackid, eci, acqbin, merid, udf1, udf2, udf3, udf4, udf5, update_datetime, insert_datetime)
values (!ERROR!-ID required., , , , , , 7, 0, , , , , , , 2016-04-21 15:23:34, 2016-04-21 15:23:34)
```

And obviously this statement fails.
This incorrect statement is generated with these `, , ,` as those values are not passed in the $input array. I was expecting `,null,null,null`.

Can you please help understand whats happening here?

**UPDATE**

I put following function in my model and it works now, but this solution doesn't look elegant to me, is there any better way to do this.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function ($model) {
        foreach ($model->toArray() as $name => $value) {
            if (empty($value) && $value !== 0 && $value !== '0') {
                $model->{$name} = null;
            }
        }

        return true;
    });

}
```

Thanks

K

Comment: show migration for its table (`up()`)

Comment: Did you use migrations while creating tables? If so, have you used nullable() for the fields you 'expect' to be null?

Comment: Well yes these fields are either null-able or  have a default value. if value passed is null in the query it would work, but the generated query is comma space comma ...

Comment: Could you add your entire model to the post?